# Is it worthwhile to fill minor cracks and holes in mortar?

Tags: brick, exterior, mortar, cracks

There are a number of small cracks and holes in the exterior on my 10-year-old brick house. These are very small and do not in any way appear structural. They are much much smaller than the weep holes, just large enough that ants and other small insects can fit through.

Should I spend the time to repair them, or would that be overkill at this point for something that is currently a non-issue? Obviously the insect issue seems pointless as a reason to do anything, since the weep holes provide much easier access.